# ggplot2 in R -- error message and then also no points being plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on my data analytics cert (google) on Coursera and there is a hands on activity with ggplot.
It tells me to type this:

```
ggplot(data = penguins) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g))
```

into the console, so I did and got this error message:

```
Error in draw_axis(break_positions = guide$key[[aesthetic]], break_labels = guide$key$.label,  : 
  lazy-load database '/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/gtable/R/gtable.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: In draw_axis(break_positions = guide$key[[aesthetic]], break_labels = guide$key$.label,  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In draw_axis(break_positions = guide$key[[aesthetic]], break_labels = guide$key$.label,  :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

When I then put quote marks around the column names, I at least got what looks like a plot, but absolutely no points on the graph.  I tried with different col names, because maybe something isn't a number? but that didn't matter, nothing happens with the plot.
Coursera is not really a whole lot of help, and I've been trying to get help from others in the course (since I'm taking it thru an organization) but haven't been able to get any help.  Is there someone out there who sees what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your gtable installation is broken. Try restarting RStudio (sometimes this helps). If the same happens again, reinstall gtable `install.packages("gtable")`. I have seen this a few times after repeatedly trying to install a package.

Comment: That error looks like something is wrong on the server where you are running R. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. I don't know if Coursera has it's own RStudio cloud instance that you are running code it but maybe logging out/logging back in again can help? Or if this is in fact your own machine, you can try reinstalling the packages you need.

Comment: Thank you all...I am running in Rstudio cloud, so that's how it is working.  I have not used that package as the course doesn't indicate to use it, so I shall try!  Thank you so much!

Comment: In trying to install gtable I get this error message:
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Comment: I figured it out!  I didn't have the tidyverse installed.